# Trigger update another table after deletion

Tags: sql-server, triggers

SQL Server 2008: I'm trying to create a trigger that will change the value of a column in `Student`, when a column in `Enroll` is deleted.

I've been trying to follow the documentation, but it's going way over my head.

Thank you.

```
CREATE TRIGGER Student_Drops
ON Enroll
AFTER DELETE
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE Student
    SET Student.Credits = Student.Credits - 3
    WHERE Student.stuID = deleted.stuID
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query would only work for one row. Can multiple rows be deleted at the same time? If so, try something like this:

```
UPDATE s
SET s.Credits = s.Credits-3
FROM Student s JOIN deleted d ON s.stuID = d.stuID
```

Comment: The problem is my original query isn't even being accepted.  It's not liking my use of `deleted`.  Is there a special way to declare `deleted`?